Windows 10 Permit Non-Admin User to Create Files on C Drive Root
I have an old application (DOS based) which must run with a non-admin account but must be capable to create files directly in the root folder of the C:\ drive.
Computers are joined to a MS AD domain.
By default, this does not work in Windows 10.
When I try to set this in the GUI (Security > Advanced, set to "this folder only"), it says "failed to enumerate the container.
Trying with "icacls.exe" like this:
   icacls C:\ /grant "myDomain\Domain Users":(OI)(M,RX,W)

seems to work fine. And if I now look in Windows Explorer GUI in Security > Advanced, I do see an entry for "Domain Users" with all rights except full control. So exactly what I expect.
I can also list the applied entries by just typing
  icacls.exe c:\ 

and it confirms the same.
So far so good.
But a regular user still cannot create a file.
Testing is easy - try to copy a file from a command prompt window into the C: drive. It won't work for a regular user. Error is:
 A required privilege is not held by the client.

But if I use an elevated command prompt, it works.
Looking at which rights those administrative users have - EXACTLY the same as "domain users".
So I disable UAC completely.
Still does not work.
For me, this is schizophrenic - the rights are the SAME for the admins as thsi regular user, yet only the admins can create files in C:.
Are there some hidden rights I cannot see or give as regular mortal?
And where do I apply to obtain those divine rights?

What you want is impossible without elevating the permissions of the application. The root directory of the system drive is a protected folder. UAC CANNOT be disabled completely on supported versions of Windows 10 or Windows 11. Even if you could the root directory would still be protected and would still require the permission of the process to be elevated

So there is no way? Note that I do not want the ability to write to the entire C drive - only to create files right in the root directory itself.

Not the question, but your DOS application will probably run OK on D:  (or on a floppy disk, A:) Use Subst or another method to create a D: drive from a folder, and put the DOS application on D:.

Use virtualization to run the old DOS program. For example, you can install DOS 6.22 or other DOS versions under VirtualBox or an alternative, and keep using that app even if you must upgrade to another version of Windows, or even under Linux or other operating system.
VirtualBox allowed me to run a 32-bit only application on a 64-bit PC to create installation media for a 32-bit machine without OS, for example.
